Is there a rhetorical device to describe the use of ", then,"?
Is there a name to describe the use of ", then," after the subject of a sentence for dramatic effect when reaching a conclusion?

Education, then, beyond all other devices of human origin, is the great equalizer of the conditions of men, - the balance wheel of the social machinery.
Horace Mann


A “techne of YouTube performance,” then, is a form of music-theoretical knowledge that exists at the intersection of analytical detail, virtuosic performance ability, practical instrumental considerations, and an awareness of one’s audience and the communicative tendencies of social media.
William O'Hara


Why do you think it a rhetorical device? It usually follows an argument setting out a case, and means 'therefore'.

Hmm, honestly not sure if it's a rhetorical device. I thought it was a neat addition that added emphasis to the argument and was wondering if there was a name to pin to it. It has a unique ring to it that I thought it might be more than just another adverb in the sentence.

By definition, the cited examples don't give enough context, since including ,then / therefore after the subject (or Hence / Thus before it) must be a reference to prior context establishing the truth of what follows.

@FumbleFingers It is true that it is possible to look at "then" as a time adverbial—"at a given time in the past"—but that seems an unlikely possibility, particularly in the second example. Further, from a reading of the texts containing these sentences, this is not the case, "then" is clearly inferential.

@LPH: I don't think there's any possibility of then being a "time adverbial" in either of OP's examples. Partly because of the overall semantics of the utterances, but also becauseboth of them are firmly rooted in the Present: ...is the great equalizer, is a form of music-theoretical knowledge.

@FumbleFingers There is still the option of a state present, which is a tense that can be used for facts in the past: "In those days, education is the great equalizer…".

@LPH: Not in my book. That would have to be either In those days, education was the great equalizer, or [In] These days, education is the great equalizer. Which since Tony Blair's bright idea (Education, education, education) it manifestly isn't. When only 10% of the population went on to further education, the country could afford to meet the tuition and living costs of bright people from poorer backgrounds. Now it's 50%, the country can't afford it, and obviously many young people are leery of taking on the huge personal debt - so it's bravery, not brains you need!

It's a pragmatic marker, of the type Fraser labels 'discourse management markers'. It's equivalent here to the comment clause 'In the light of what we've just been saying', structuring the discourse and in this case stressing the logic behind the coming declaration. 'Therefore' is a synonym here.

@FumbleFingers I think you are right; there has to be a confusion in my mind with the historic present. //  More than  "the means by which [man] can resist the selfishness of other men" education, that is, education validated by universities, seems to be a sure means to greater wealth, but this idea that it would be  equalizing the conditions of men does not  appear to reflect what  reality shows; however, general education seems to bring up the poorest's conditions to a higher, more civilized level.

"Then" is in this context an adverb meant to provide a connection; this is why in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language (Quirk et al., 1985) the type of adverbial that "then" embodies in this sort of sentence is called a conjunct. There is no rhetorical device involved, and the discussion remains in the domain of syntax.

(OLD) then adverb   /ðen/
used to show the logical result of a particular statement or situation

If you miss that train then you'll have to get a taxi.
‘My wife's got a job in Glasgow.’ ‘I take it you'll be moving, then.’
‘You haven't done anything to upset me.’ ‘So what's wrong, then?’
Why don't you hire a car? Then you'll be able to visit more of the area.



(CoGEL) § 8.135
[…] conjuncts indicate how the speaker 'views the connection between two linguistic units', [but] such an indication does
not conversely entail the use of a conjunct. The semantic role of expressing a
relation between two units can frequently be fulfilled by an adjunct. Compare
the following (where a pronoun, as frequently, functions as a linking device):

It was snowing, and in spite of this Mona went cycling.

The adverbial here which conjoins and indicates a concessive relation is an
adjunct, as we see from its propensity to be focused in a cleft sentence:

. . . and it was in spite of this that Mona went cycling.

By contrast, in:

It was snowing, and nonetheless Mona went cycling.

the same conjoining function with the same concessive relation is fulfilled
grammatically by  a conjunct :
*. . . and it was nonetheless that Mona went cycling. (user LPH: grammatically unacceptable, impossibility of writing cleft sentences shows the non-adjunct nature of "nonetheless")
Conjuncts thus both indicate the relation and are demonstrably outside the
syntactically integrated clause structure which admits adjuncts.
Moreover, there is one significant respect in which we must relax the
semantic characteristic concerning the conjoining of linguistic units. It is
possible for conjuncts to be used as discourse-initial items. Thus speech may
actually begin, in the following way, given a particular context of situation:

So you're LÈAVing, then! (user LPH: "LÈAV" represents a stressed syllable with falling intonation)

[…]

